# Which Rabbi claimed he was metaphorically born at the top of a mountain?

Tags: sources-mekorot, rabbis, quotations

I once heard that a rebbe claimed that his great levels were compared to a child born at the top of a mountain. Does anyone know where this is recorded?

Comment: I'm not sure what that means. Can you elaborate?

Comment: The reason I ask is because the quote likely *won't* be in English, but rather in Hebrew...or possibly Yiddish (do you know what relative time period this quote was supposed to have been said?)

Comment: think it was either the sfas emes or imrei emes but ן'm not sure

Answer (score 10):

*Nesivei Yeshurun al HaTorah*<sup>1</sup> (פרשת תולדות) cites a story where the [*Sefas Emes*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yehudah_Aryeh_Leib_Alter) implies that he started at a lofty spiritual level due to the greatness of his illustrious grandfather, the [*Chidushei HaRI"M*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yitzchak_Meir_Alter). To convey this idea, the *Sefas Emes* employs the analogy of a small child born at the summit of a lofty mountain:

> ואלה תולדות יצחק בן אברהם אברהם הוליד את יצחק (כה, יט)… ותמהו המפרשים דסיפיה דקרא לאו רישיה שבא לומר תולדות יצחק ואמר תולדות אברהם, ויש לבאר עפ"י המשל הידוע מה"שפת אמת" שהתחיל להנהיג בגיל צעיר מאד ושאלוהו ע"ז האיך יתכן לנהל עדת חסידים שברובם זקנים ששימשו את גדולי הצדיקים, ואמר בזה ע"ד משל למקום גבוה מאד שכדי להעפיל לפסגתו הי' לוקח הרבה זמן, וכל שנות אנוש עלי חלד ולואי שיספיקו לזה, והי' זקן אחד שכל שנות חייו הקדיש לזה להגיע למרומי ההר, וכשהגיע לשם מצא שם תינוק אחד, ושאלו האיך אתה מגיע לכאן, הרי כל שנות חיי אני חותר לכאן וענה לו אני נולדתי כאן, בפסגת ההר, והנמשל מובן… והיינו דקאמר קרא ואלה תולדות יצחק בן אברהם, שמיד בתחילתו זכה לכל המדרגות משום דאברהם הוליד את יצחק שנולד כבר אצל אברהם בפסגת המדרגות…

*Orchos Mussar*<sup>2</sup> (discourse 28, subsection "זכות אבות", p. 293) cites a similar analogy in the name of [R' Henech of Aleksander](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chanokh_Heynekh_HaKohen_Levin), the predecessor of the *Sefas Emes*:

> וכן המשיל האדמו"ר רבי העניך מאלכסנדר זצ"ל משל נמרץ: אדם מבוגר טיפס לראש ההר, הדבר עלה לו ביגיעה עצומה. לתדהמתו, כשהגיע לפסגת ההר מצא שם ילד קטן. שאל המבוגר את הילד: הלא הדרך לכאן כ"כ מיגעת ואין זה לפי כוחך להעפיל לפסגת ההר, א"כ, כיצד הגעת אתה לכאן? השיב לו הילד: אני לא טיפסתי לכאן! - אני נולדתי כאן! האבא שלי הוא שטיפס! זהו הענין של זכות אבות וכח האבות הנטוע בנו. האבוה"ק השרישו בכלל ישראל רוממות נפלאה, שעל ידה, תחילת הנקודה שלנו נמצאת כבר בפסגת ההר הגבוה.

---

<sup>1</sup> <sub>By Rabbi Ya'akov Yisrael Luria, *Ra"M* at [Yeshivas Beis Avraham](https://he.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D7%99%D7%A9%D7%99%D7%91%D7%AA_%D7%91%D7%99%D7%AA_%D7%90%D7%91%D7%A8%D7%94%D7%9D) in Meah Shearim; [pub. 2002](https://books.google.com/books?id=k00HRAAACAAJ)</sub>

<sup>2</sup> <sub>By Rabbi Doron David Gold, *Mashgiach Ruchani* at [Yeshivas Derech Chochma](https://he.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D7%99%D7%A9%D7%99%D7%91%D7%AA_%D7%93%D7%A8%D7%9A_%D7%97%D7%9B%D7%9E%D7%94) in Har Nof; pub. 2001</sub>

Comment: See also http://www.gfn.co.il/index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=29395&confim=1: לקראת סיום ה"רב שיח‮" ‬לאחר שקיימתי מצוות‮ "‬רב‮" ‬ורבתי עם כולם ספרתי את הסיפור הבא‮: ‬כשאדמו"ר מגור הראשון‮ (‬ר‮' ‬יצחק מאיר אלתר בעל‮ "‬חידושי הרים‮" ‬חלה הוא זימן את נכדו‮, ‬ר‮' ‬יהודה אריה לייב‮ - "‬השפת אמת‮" ‬והודיע לו שהוא יהיה האדמו"ר מגור‮. ‬ר‮' ‬יהודה אריה לייב‮, ‬שהיה בן ‮91 ‬התרגש נורא ואמר לסבא שהוא לא ראוי לתפקיד הרם‮. ‬הסבא הרגיע את נכדו וספר מעשיה נחמדה‮: ‬היו היה גבר שהחליט לטפס לפסגת ההר הכי גבוה‮ - ‬... "? ‬ענה הילד‮: "‬אדוני‮, ‬אני לא טיפסתי‮, ‬אני נולדתי בראש ההר‮..." ‬ו